# Prove that at least one subsequence of $s_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove **at least one subsequence of $s_{n}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ converges to $1.$** Here is my first attempt:

> A sequence $t_{n}$ is defined as follows: $$f(n)=2n,\quad n=1,2,\ldots.$$ Then, $s_{t_{n}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{t_{n}}}.$ We now have to show that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an integer $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies that $$|s_{t_{n}}-1|=|\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{t_{n}}}-1|=\frac{1}{t_{n}+1}<\varepsilon.$$ By the archimedean property of the real field, there is a positive integer $m$ such that $$\varepsilon m>1.$$ Let $N$ be the integer such that $$t_{n}+1>m,\quad n\ge N.$$ In conclusion, it is true that $$\frac{1}{t_{n}+1}<\frac{1}{m}<\varepsilon.$$

My questions are:

- Is there anything wrong?
- Is it too long? If so, can you give me some alternatives?

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to define $\;t_n=2n\;$ ? That $\;f(n)\;$ only makes things cumbersome.

Comment: I presume you can't/haven't yet studied arithmetic of limits? And I think your way is fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio I agree that $t_{n}=2n$ is better. For the second comment, Yes. I'm yet to study them.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you for letting me know that it's okay. In fact, it's the first time I ever try to "calculate" limits so that I need some supervision.